# How do I serialize data from non-form elements and make it accessable from params[:model]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app which loads information from an external API and displays it on a page. This is done in Sinatra which gets the information and puts it a temporary model instance (which is NOT saved), so it is easier to access all its propertys in the view.

Now when the user clicks a link I want the model instance to be saved to the database, which I think only can be done via AJAX etc. because the last request already finished and none of the  instances is still alive. I thought I needed to extract all the information of the corresponding HTML elements and make an AJAX-Post to another route.

My problem is now, I want to be able to create(and save) the model using `@model = Model.create(params[:model])`. It would be clear what to do using a form, but that is not an option because all the data is displayed within a table and each table row is one instance of the model.

How do I serialize the data from the table row in which the clicked link is, so I can use it as described above?

**UPDATE**

- I am using *MULTIPLE* instances of the object class, each in one tablerow!
- I am using DataMapper, only the temporary objects are not stored!
- I **dont** want to clutter up my whole setup!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a pretty easy solution. It was nothing more than getting all the required values from the DOM and putting them into an Array!

**application.js:**

```
$(".enable").click(function() {
    var table_row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var model_array = new Array;
    var elements_with_information = jRow.find("[name]");

    elements_with_information.each(function() {
            // Doing some checking on which kind of element 
            // it actually is and then basically doing:
            model_array.push($(this).text());
    });

    // Constructing nested array to use `params[:model]`
    var data = { "model" : {
        "property1": model_array[0],
        "property2": model_array[1]
    }};

    // Now doing the AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        url: "/model/doshit",
        type: "POST",
        data: data
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider [ActiveResource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html)? You can use ActiveResource to maintain object state. If your REST API follows convention it would be very easy to map resource.

Regarding second half sending back data to your controller, you could store in hidden variable(s) and on post it should be easy to construct back the object and persist it to database.

Something like

```
#model
class MyModel < ActiveResource::Base
  # set configs here
end

# To fetch record from REST API in controller or whatever
MyModel.find(1)

#in controller on form submit or AJAX
post "/path" do
  MyModel.new(params[:myModel])
end
```

**Update**
To maintain state of object without using hidden form

in javascript you can have something like

```
var myModel = #{myModel.to_json}; #Ruby interpolation in HAML it will depend on templating language
```

on certain action you can update the JSON object

and to post using AJAX

```
$.post("post/path", myModel);
```

**More Update**

In External JS

```
function my_js_function(obj) {
/* do something useful here like setting up object hash etc
*/
}
```

In Ruby Template

```
<script>
  var myObj = #{myObj.json}
  my_js_function(myObj);
</script>
```

Comment: Well, I am using DataMapper. The point actually is to persist it only on request to do so and to do it without a form (hidden inputs). Accessing the data is no problem, but forming a data string is difficult to me.

Comment: How are you going to maintain the state of the object on client side? Please see the updated answer

Comment: This looks like it is worth a try, but I have multiple model instances and I want to have the javascript in seperate files. Also I am using slim a templating language.

Comment: JavaScript does not have `hashmap` sort of thing, you could build a json map for your object. For example get array of objects and then `objMap = {}` then iterate over object array and map it `objMap[objArr[i].id]= objArr[i]` OR EVEN Simpler take a look at [angularjs](http://angularjs.org/)

Comment: But this doesn't really help me, there is still a problem with not being able to use interpolation in external javascript files!

Comment: You can create JSON object and pass the value as function parameter to your external JavaScript file.

Comment: But this defeats the whole point of having extra files! In the mean time, I figured a solution.